# Declaration of template <class __declspec(dllexport) windowclass> giving an error in vs2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

We are migrating our projects from vs2005 to VS2015 .In one of the project we are using below template declaration

```
template <class __declspec(dllexport) WindowClass>
```

In 2005,it is building successfully but in vs2015 getting below error.

> 'WindowClass': illegal type for non-type template parameter 'WindowClass'

I am not sure about the use of dllexport inside a template . Anyone know why it is useful and why it is not working in vs2015?

Comment: I don't think you should use the ````__declspec(dllexport)```` in a template declaration. Removing it should solve the problem.

Comment: Yea ,it is builind if I remove the export statement but just thinking it may impact in runtime